# add_rewrite_rule refuses to function

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to create a custom redirect on my local machine using MAMP. From the Wordpress codex I have the following code as a simple starting point. No matter what I try I cannot get this simple solution to function as expected. I am running the latest version of Wordpress, I have saved the permalinks to flush the redirects and changed the theme to eleminate this as variable. My xampp has mod_rewrite enabled.

I simply want to redirect: http://example.com/?p=95 to http://example.com/leaf/95

The code is as follows:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
    
      }
      add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

My htaccess is the basic wordpress version and I am not using any plugins in my build.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to redirect `?p=95` to `/leaf/95/` or `?page_id`? Your code has one but your question has the other. Are your permalinks set to plain? Also, can you describe your actual goal? What does 95 represent in this situation?

Comment: Jacob, my permalinks are set to post name. The code above is just a starting point for me to redirect some urls. What I am trying to achieve is redirect www.myurl.com/book?event=12 to www.myurl.com/12/book

But no redirect code I use work for me. The above code is a basic example from Wordpress Codex.

Comment: Ok so let's get some terminology straight first. Redirects and rewrites are different things. Does `/12/book` already work? If so, then you just need to redirect. If not, then you need a rewrite to make it work, not a redirect.

Comment: My apologies, sorry to confuse you when you are trying to help. I am trying to rewrite. /12/book does not exist.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I suggest updating your question with the actual URL format you want to use, because the question you asked will get the wrong answer for what you actually want, based on your comments.